# Why TypeScript forces me to return in unreachable code?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
import { Point, LineString } from 'geojson';

export function getIconPoint(geometrie: Point | LineString): Point {
  if (geometrie.type === 'Point') {
    return geometrie;
  }

  if (geometrie.type === 'LineString') {
    return {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: geometrie.coordinates[0],
    }
  }

  // unreachable
}
```

After the two `if` statements the code is supposed unreachable because `Point` and `LineString` are discriminated interfaces based on their `type` field. Still TypeScript is not happy and asks me to return something, but I don't want to add anything else than `Point` as the return value type:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not
> include 'undefined'

How do I fix this in a clean way?

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgBQsAdjANHAMhgUwGUYoMBzOAXzgDMoIQ4BycgiAKwGcJ1mBuAFCCCAD0iw6AV3QBjGMF5w2MAJKzeqDDAAUbRgVLACALhRpMcAD55CJMunIBKM1ssJBcOMFpw97EEMyAgA6GABPMAI4AF44ljcYZidETy84KEMpKHRlAKDjIS8qYS8fP31Ao1CIqNj45nx0YiNHZNT0jKycjs64WtMEiySsNM6NaAATDABDGAIuM0qC0ImoafQ5hYBtAAYAXVHOkuLSuAB6c7gZTJnZAAsZgCMAGwJBKiA)

Comment: Nothing really ensures that the `type` can **only** be those two values. The code at the end is not really unreachable, therefore you must return something from it.

Comment: It works with a switch: https://tsplay.dev/mL4Zkm

Comment: @jonrsharpe indeed that's interesting, would love to know why this control flow structure behaves differently.

Comment: @Alejandro the parameter is either `Point` or `LineString`, so `geometrie.type` is `"Point" | "LineString"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bet is that it only works with control flow blocks that are linked together (you found `switch` but `if` `else` works too according to the other answer)

Comment: Interestingly, if you type `geometrie` after the second block and mouseover it, it will have type `never`.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance yes I knew that, and I thought it was enough for TypeScript not to tell me to `return`

Comment: @GuerricP `if` `else` works because it's exhaustive _without_ any type information; the `switch` isn't. But `if` `else if` _doesn't_ work even though the compiler knows that `'Point'` is the only remaining value for `geometrie.type`. So I guess it's just a limitation of the control flow analysis.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, well thanks for your comment, if you can explain why `switch` works and feel like writing an answer, I'll accept it because it seems to be the better solution and I'd love to know why it works

Comment: a switch will be the cleanest way, but if you insist on avoiding it, you can also `throw Error()` in case of unexpected values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the code examples below, I've enabled the compiler option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess). This has the effect of enforcing that the code below checks that values exist at specific indexes in arrays (e.g. coordinates).

To start, let's examine which types can be discriminated:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzjAnmApnAChYA7GAGmTUwBl90BlGKfAczgF84AzKCEOAInvQgBWAZwh5uAbgBQk1gFc8AYxjBRcPjACSC0TnwwAFH07pawdAC5suAnAA+cCnmqm89AJSJJcNfxAm66FLeAPTBAHoA-NLewKxwhr7+ZgB0qBhwALxZPLoE3B4IXt4+xqaBRSHhUd5MRegANkKYsfFGfmWppJnZ3I7OdK75nsUl7QFBxaGRRbXeDU2jSeUjk1WStUA)

```ts
function getIconPoint(geometrie: Point | LineString) {
  geometrie;
  //^? (parameter) geometrie: Point | LineString

  if (geometrie.type === "Point") {
    geometrie;
    //^? (parameter) geometrie: Point
  }
  else if (geometrie.type === "LineString") {
    geometrie;
    //^? (parameter) geometrie: LineString
  }
  else geometrie;
       //^? (parameter) geometrie: never
}
```

In the code above, the compiler shows us that the only two possibilities for the value of `geometrie.type` are `"Point"` and `"LineString"` because `geometrie` is `never` in the final `else` branch. This should give you confidence that you and the compiler agree about possibilities.

---

Now, you've asked two questions (one in the title and one in the body of your post). First, the title:

> Why TypeScript forces me to return in unreachable code?

The direct answer to your question is that you have (perhaps indirectly) enabled the compiler option [`noImplicitReturns`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns), but I don't think that's what's being asked.

There is an important distinction to make here, and that's the difference between exhaustiveness checks in the type system at compile time (what you have in mind) vs exhaustiveness checks at runtime (the actual definition of *unreachable*). A quick review of the error messsage:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzjAnmApnAChYA7GAGmTUwBl90BlGKfAczgF84AzKCEOAInvQgBWAZwh5uAbgBQk1gFc8AYxjBRcPjACSC0TnwwAFH07pawdAC5suAnAA+cCnmqm89AJSXdNpAHoAVHAAolAcUJJwEZFR0TGxcfHxAH7JyZIAYvJKKnhwADYAhgoA1kJw6HgAJgxwUCayUDlCMPkw6CDl8PmVNXUNJBhwFRDopXgQ8PgKubIVmADk8rOslBVzAHT6AEwAzABsu25wfj7SEcCscIb87aboa6gDALzPPF4w3Ie1MPU5Rjd06Ck4Tg50ufxMAPupDgz0ePEczjorg+iGBES+P1RMQeFle1nehDRkW00CqeBaI0s4NuaxJUDJFKEAG0AAwAXWI-iCIWgRIiKQFAr5cAyimUqgKxVK5TJjAxfSaFPaNi6FR63z6OMGw1G4xBimmszgC0q6GWTlWGx2+0OxyJTCkESYkmdQA)

```ts
function getIconPoint(geometrie: Point | LineString): Point { /* Error
                                                      ~~~~~
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.(2366) */

  if (geometrie.type === "Point") return geometrie;

  if (geometrie.type === "LineString") {
    return {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: geometrie.coordinates[0],
    };
  }
}
```

In the type system, it is not valid to call the function above with any object which isn't assignable to either `Point` or `LineString`. However, even though that's true, the function body has three code paths at **runtime** where the type system doesn't exist:

1. one which stops at the `return` statement in the case that `geometrie.type === "Point"`
2. one which stops at the `return` statement in the case that `geometrie.type === "LineString"`
3. one final path where neither of those cases are matched and the function implicitly returns `undefined`

To illustrate this, here's an example of calling your function with different values at **runtime**:

```js
function getIconPoint (geometrie) {
  if (geometrie.type === "Point") return geometrie;

  if (geometrie.type === "LineString") {
    return {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: geometrie.coordinates[0],
    };
  }
}

const testCases = [
  ["point", {type: "Point"}],
  ["LineString", {type: "LineString", coordinates: []}],
  ["Neither", {type: "Neither"}],
];

for (const [name, value] of testCases) {
  console.log(name, getIconPoint(value));
}
```

As you can see by running the code snippet, the third test case logs `"Neither" undefined` to the console — it's not actually *unreachable*.

`{ type: "Neither" }` is not a valid argument to call the function with in TypeScript, but that's not related to the [`noImplicitReturns`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns) option.

Moving on to your second question:

> How do I fix this in a clean way?

Here are two options for satisfying the compiler using the code you've shown as a basis:

You can simply return the `LineString` possibility when `geometrie.type` is not equal to `"Point"`. This has the same effect as `return`ing from an `else` or the `default` case in a `switch` statement:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzjAnmApnAChYA7GAGmTUwBl90BlGKfAczgF84AzKCEOAInvQgBWAZwh5uAbgBQk1gFc8AYxjBRcPjACSC0TnwwAFH07pawdAC5suAnAA+cCnmqm89AJSXdNhJLhxgrHCG-CAmdOgAdKgYcAC88TxeMNxucFAmslB4aiFhZlK+cNp4QvAA2qzAUKU4QsDKogC6cTnGppHa0AAm+ACGMOhCUn4BQQCEldUwtfUqeKkwABYcAO5wTmsAolAcUPrcjs50rusA5L1wYL1CcF2YnVBdongAl4MpBX7pMJnZPn5+aIWRLWZKEQp+B49PD9QaWSY1CB1Bp4cF+JhSJiSIA)

```ts
function getIconPoint(geometrie: Point | LineString): Point {
  if (geometrie.type === "Point") return geometrie;

  const [firstPosition] = geometrie.coordinates;
  if (!firstPosition) throw new Error("LineString n'a pas de coordonnées");

  return {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: firstPosition,
  };
}
```

You can throw an error in the case that some other code attempts to call the function with an invalid argument:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzjAnmApnAChYA7GAGmTUwBl90BlGKfAczgF84AzKCEOAInvQgBWAZwh5uAbgBQk1gFc8AYxjBRcPjACSC0TnwwAFH07pawdAC5suAnAA+cCnmqm89AJSXdNhJLhxgrHCG-CAmdOgAdKgYcAC88TxeMNxucFAmslB4aiFhZlK+-oHBxqaR0ZjxsTyOznSuKYiFftp4QvAA2qzAUO04QsDKogC6cTml4RHa0AAm+ACGMOhCUn5+AUEAhN29MP2DKnipMAAWHADucE6XAKJQHFD63LU09Yx4AOTzcGDzQnAzTDTKAzUR4ACXyxSBTWaQyWSasL8FUs3CS3EIzTWwLmeEWy0sOz6EAGQzwmNhTFWzGkyLOEEu1zgdweTwAqk4AB4YJToGbjUJlaGSJiSIA)

```ts
function getIconPoint(geometrie: Point | LineString): Point {
  if (geometrie.type === "Point") return geometrie;

  if (geometrie.type === "LineString") {
    const [firstPosition] = geometrie.coordinates;
    if (!firstPosition) throw new Error("LineString n'a pas de coordonnées");

    return {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: firstPosition,
    };
  }

  throw new Error("Unexpected geometrie");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case why not just omit the `else`?
If you have only two options that is..

```js
import { Point, LineString } from 'geojson';

export function getIconPoint(geometrie: Point | LineString): Point {
  if (geometrie.type === 'Point') {
    return geometrie;
  }

  return {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: geometrie.coordinates[0],
  }
}
```

Ditto if you had more options btw, simply omit the last condition.
Typescript shouldn't complain when it's written like this.

Obviosuly to make it even better we would probably prefer to employ an [exhaustive type-checking](https://dev.to/ddiprose/exhaustive-switch-statement-with-typescript-26dh) function of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the geometrie is one of the enumerated options, you can throw an exception at the end of the function.

`throw new Error("geometrie is neither Point nor LineString");`

And the error will go away.

Otherwise, I would go with an OOD design where you can use dispatch instead of checking type with if statements.